# Connect two comboboxes via a dictionary (with the purpose to display male or female names in the combobox)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I have a combobox where I select the gender Male or Female. Then I have another combobox where now all the names of people are displayed (without distinction of gender).

I would like to select Male from the first combobox and automatically display (without button) the Male names in the second combobox. The same thing for Female names. Thank you

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()  
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
window.configure(bg='#f3f2f2')

style = ttk.Style(window)
style.theme_use('clam')

John = {"Name": "John", "Years": 1980, "Gender": "Male"}
Linda = {"Name": "Linda", "Years": 1983, "Gender": "Female"}
Martin = {"Name": "Martin", "Years": 1981, "Gender": "Male"}


gender=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 12)
gender.place(x=5, y=60)
gender['value'] = ["Male", "Female"]
gender.set("Gender?")

all_name=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 12)
all_name.place(x=150, y=60)
all_name['value'] = [x["Name"] for x in [John, Linda, Martin]]
all_name.set("All Name")



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event on `gender` and update `value` option of `all_name` inside the event callback:

```py
...
def on_gender_selected(event):
    selected = gender.get()
    # get the names for selected gender
    all_name['value'] = [x['Name'] for x in [John, Linda, Martin] if x['Gender'] == selected]
    all_name.set('') # clear current selection

gender.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_gender_selected)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the NameError: name 'gender' is not defined. I must have done something wrong. Can you show me the full code please?

Comment: Just put the code before creating `all_name`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, thanks. For distraction and sleep fatigue, I had inserted it before all_name. In fact it seemed strange to me. Thank you. Voted!